# Simplify multiple try and except in for loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, try-catch

I  have a loop within a function that scrapes fighter meta from a well known mma site.
The function works however, I need to assign a default value of None if any of the soup.find or soup.findall variables raise an attribute or index error.

**I have tried to use this function without success:**

```
    def ex_handler(i):
        try:
            return i
        except (AttributeError, IndexError): 
            return None

last_name = ex_handler(soup.find('span', class_='fn').text.strip().split()[1])
```

**Code:**

```
def get_fighter_meta(fighter_urls):
        """Scrapes meta from fighters page"""
        for counter, fighter_url in enumerate(fighter_urls, start=1):
            soup = get_soup(fighter_url)
    
            try:
                first_name = soup.find('span', class_='fn').text.strip().split()[0]
            except (AttributeError, IndexError):
                first_name = None
    
            # todo  try & except alternative to catch exceptions on all soup variables
            last_name = soup.find('span', class_='fn').text.strip().split()[1]
            full_name = f'{first_name} {last_name}'
            nickname = soup.find('span', class_='nickname').text.strip()
            image_url = f"https://www.xxxxxx.com/{soup.find('img', attrs={'itemprop': 'image'})['src']}"
    
            dob = soup.find('span', attrs={'itemprop': 'birthDate'}).text.strip()
    
            location = soup.find('span', class_='locality').text.strip()
            nationality = soup.find('strong', attrs={'itemprop': 'nationality'}).text.strip()
            association = soup.find('span', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'}).text.strip()
    
            height = soup.find('span', class_='item height').text.strip()[-9:-2]
            weight = soup.find('span', class_='item weight').text.strip()[-9:-2].strip()
            weight_class = soup.find('strong', class_='title').text.strip()
    
            win_loss_loop = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('span', class_='counter')]
    
            wins = win_loss_loop[0]
            losses = win_loss_loop[1]
    
            graph_tag_loop = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('span', class_='graph_tag')]
    
            win_ko = graph_tag_loop[0][:2].strip()
            win_submission = graph_tag_loop[1][:2].strip()
            win_decisions = graph_tag_loop[2][:2].strip()
    
            loss_ko = graph_tag_loop[3][0][:2].strip()
            loss_submission = graph_tag_loop[4][:2].strip()
            loss_decisions = graph_tag_loop[5][:2].strip()
    
            fighter_meta = {
                'First_name': first_name,
                'Last_name': last_name,
                'Full name': full_name,
                'Nickname': nickname,
                'Image_url': image_url,
                'Date_of_birth': dob,
                'Location': location,
                'Nationality': nationality,
                'Association': association,
                'Height': height,
                'Weight': weight,
                'Weight_class': weight_class,
                'Wins': wins,
                'Losses': losses,
                'Win_by_ko': win_ko,
                'Win_by_submission': win_submission,
                'Win_decision': win_decisions,
                'Loss_by_ko': loss_ko,
                'Loss_by_submission': loss_submission,
                'Loss_by_desision': loss_decisions
            }
            fighter_data.append(fighter_meta)
            print(f'Saving: {full_name}  - {counter} of {len(fighter_urls)}')
```

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments are evaluated before calling the function, so you can't catch the error in the function that way. You need to pass a function that gets called by `ex_handler`, so you can use a lambda.

```
def ex_handler(f):
    try:
        return f()
    except (AttributeError, IndexError): 
        return None

last_name = ex_handler(lambda: soup.find('span', class_='fn').text.strip().split()[1])
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  would this method be the most efficient when applying to multiple variables?

Comment: In practice I would just assign the result of `soup.find()` to a variable and use an `if` statement. This method would be more useful if there were lots of nested expressions that need to be tested.